# Application of date formatting on x-axis text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to apply `d3.time.format("%b-%Y")` to the dates used on the x-axis.

Here is the code which adds the axis and labels

```
var xLabels = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (margin.top + height + 12) + ")");

var formatDateOutputX = d3.time.format("%b-%Y");

xLabels.selectAll("text.xAxis")
  .data(BarData)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.dt;                      //<< returns dates
    //return formatDateOutputX(d.dt); //<< NOTHING RETURNED
  })
  .attr({
    'text-anchor': "middle",
    transform: function(d, i) {
      var x = (i * (width / BarData.length)) + ((width / BarData.length - barPadding) / 2);
      var y = 20;
      return 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')rotate(-90)';
    },
    dy: "0.35em", //dx: "-1.05em",
    'class': "xAxis"
  });
```

The above relates to the lines of code 285-309 of this visualisation: https://plnkr.co/edit/3d5UhM?p=preview

Hoping someone can help as this will be a fairly common manipulation that I will want to apply. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing a valid date to `formatDateOutputX` so it doesn't know how to process it. You have to parse the value appropriately and you can do it in many ways. Since d3 provides a `parse` method to `time.format` that is probably the best way to follow.

In your case something like this will work:

```
    var formatDateOutputX = d3.time.format("%b-%Y");
    var readDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse;

    xLabels.selectAll("text.xAxis")
      .data(BarData)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return formatDateOutputX(readDate(d.dt));
      })
```

Check the [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/jDh0RTJmrWXPJXYTyj8i?p=preview).